Executing NSBatchInsertRequest creates duplicates
When I fetch the entities after a batch insert in the main queue's managed object context to update my SwiftUI list, I notice there are always duplicates (to be precise, literal doubling of each entity).
I perform a batch insert of the files the user imports through the "import files" method in the Manager class. Then, I fetch them into the managed object context of the main queue to update my SwiftUI list.
class DataController {
    static let shared = DataController()

    func createNewBackgroundContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let taskContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
        taskContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        return taskContext
    }
}

class Manager {
    func importFiles(from urls: [URL]) async {
        let importContext = DataController.shared.createNewBackgroundContext()
        
        var objects: [[String: Any]] = []
        
        for url in urls {
            if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                let metadata = getMetadata(url: url)
                
                let audioFileName = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent                  
                let fileExtension = url.pathExtension
                let artist = metadata?.value(forKey: "artist") as? String ?? "Unknown Artist"
                let album = metadata?.value(forKey: "album") as? String ?? "Unknown Album"
                let genre = metadata?.value(forKey: "genre") as? String ?? "Unknown Genre"
                let composer = metadata?.value(forKey: "composer") as? String ?? "Unknown Composer"
                let year = metadata?.value(forKey: "year") as? String ?? "Unknown Release Year"
                let importDate = Date()
                let artwork = audioFileName + ".\(fileExtension)"
                let trackNumber = metadata?.value(forKey: "trackNumber") as? Int ?? -1
                
                let properties: [String: Any] = [
                    "name": audioFileName,
                    "artist": artist,
                    "album": album,
                    "genre": genre,
                    "year": year,
                    "composer": composer,
                    "importDate": importDate,
                    "trackNumber": trackNumber,
                    "artwork": artwork,
                    "fileExtension": fileExtension,
                    "favourite": false
                ]
                objects.append(properties)

                //Save the file to disk
                save(url: url, with: audioFileName + ".\(fileExtension)")
            }
            
            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
             
//objects array is confirmed to have the right number of items to be inserted

await importContext.perform { [weak self] in
        guard let self else { return }
                    
    let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: AudioFile.entity(), objects: objects)
    batchInsertRequest.resultType = .objectIDs
    
    let result = try? importContext.execute(batchInsertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult
    let objs = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] ?? []

//The number of ids is always double here for some reason...

    let changes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSInsertedObjectIDsKey: objs]
    // Merge changes
    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [moc])
}

        await MainActor.run {
             SongsListViewModel.shared.fetchAudioFiles()
        }
    }
}

class SongsListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AllSongsListViewModel()
    
    @Published var audioFiles = [AudioFile]()
    private let moc = DataController.shared.container.viewContext
    
    func fetchAudioFiles() {
        let fetchRequest = AudioFile.fetchRequest()
        if let audioFiles = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest) {
            self.audioFiles = audioFiles
        }
    }
}


What troubleshooting have you done here, so you have duplicate entries but did you check if you have duplicate files, did you add any print statements in your code to follow the flow of the execution, etc... It's almost impossible to reproduce this for anyone else so we need all the information you have.

No duplicate files were written. No duplicate objects to be inserted into batch request were created as well. I am guessing it is because of multiple object context issues since there is both a main and private context?

To add on, the duplicates occur only once I immediately fetch the audio files. Once I close the app and refetch the audio files, there are no duplicates.

I have found the source of the duplicate entries. If anyone cares to explain why "shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically" should be set to true to prevent a NSBatchInsertRequest from inserting a copy for each entity, that would be great.
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
//I have set this property of the description to false all along. Apparently this must be set to true to avoid duplicates when performing a NSBatchInsertRequest
//description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = false
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

There were zero information regarding this on stack overflow or any mention regarding this in the Apple Documentation.
